# how to use on activity result for going through more then one activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity, onactivityresult

I have made a form in that I have a textView field called"CategoryID",now when the user click on it it will go to a categoryListActivity,In that activity a List with categories are them ,In that List some of categories having subcategories and some not,So from that i want its name and Id ,But my problem is how to send name and id if category may having subcategory?

my basic logic(what i need is):

categoryID(TextView) ->onClick - >goto "CategoryActivity" --> if "category" having subcategory it will go to next activity "subcategory" otherwise it will redirect to the form with "category name" and "ID" if not it will goto "SubCategoryActivity" and from there a list will there the item which i will click will send to form field "categoryName(TextView)".Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` to achieve this. This flag allows an activity to delegate the responsibility for returning the result to another activity.

`MainActivity` starts `CategoryActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`. If `CategoryActivity` realizes that the user needs to choose a subcategory, then it starts `SubcategoryActivity` like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubcategoryActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
    intent.putExtra("category", category); // Pass the chosen category to the next activity
    startActivity(intent);
    // This activity can finish now. SubcategoryActivity will return the result
    finish();
```

Notice that `SubcategoryActivity` is started using `startActivity()` and NOT `startActivityForResult()`. `SubcategoryActivity` should, however, set a result before it calls `finish()`. That result will be returned to `MainActivity` in `onActivityResult()` when `SubcategoryActivity` calls `finish()`.